# our great men and women in Blue

Tags: word-usage

I understand "our great men and women in Blue" as "our respectable policemen and policewomen". Am I on the right track?

We know the slogan "Back the Blue" chanted by many people refers to "Support the Police". So I guess "Blue" in the tweet below means "Police".

> Donald J. Trump @realDonaldTrump
> ·Jan 7
> I am asking for everyone at the U.S. Capitol to remain peaceful. No violence! Remember, WE are the Party of Law & Order – respect the Law and **our great men and women in Blue**. Thank you!

Comment: "Great" doesn't mean "respectable" here. It can mean many things but it is often used  - weakly - to signal one's approval of something: "These sausages are great". "This great country of ours". Teachers often encourage children to find stronger adjectives than the similarly-overused "nice". You are right: he means the men and women in blue uniforms. "WE", "Party of Law & Order", "Law" and "Blue" shouldn't have capital letters.

Answer (score 1):

Many police forces around the world (not all) have blue uniforms. The capitalisations by Trump, of 'Blue' and 'Law' are incorrect.